# Cannot decrypt simple string in Python using AES128

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

I get `k_dh` from a server as an int:

```
k_dh = 119503520092559061448841199568006105540928326398312683239977940696158565641455510032815414544631246909440988946150279621651776468095255682411875734678137913094987602893885584001153718721315823055714857464429284631169985212295788520092555311452302786716587927084384268157895132756379511638032100445133977318010
```

I have to get the last 16 bytes from this and I do this way, converting it in `HEX` and getting the last 32 `HEX` chars:

```
key = str(hex(int(k_dh)))[-32:]
```

In addition, I receive from the server also the ciphertext:
`chipertext = a6e0397f88668030aa861bb09fee236d`

I convert it in bytes:
`ciphertext = b'\xa6\xe09\x7f\x88f\x800\xaa\x86\x1b\xb0\x9f\xee#m'`

using: `ciphertext = bytes.fromhex(ciphertext)`

And then I try to decrypt without success:

```
key = unhexlify(key)
IV = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)


decipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,IV)
plaintext = decipher.decrypt(to_decrypt)
print(plaintext)
```

Which give me `b'\x8d]\xd9)I*\x90\xe52\x88\x04\xc7\xcc+8/'`.
It should be a readable sentence, something is wrong but I don't know where.

Hope that someone could find my mistake.
Thanks!

Comment: The IV, however, is random. How do you expect that match to the IV of the encryption? Did'nt they say something about how to recover the IV?

Comment: the IV is random you must use the same IV used to encrypt the message and not a randomly generated IV.